# Human Readable Date in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, time

I am trying to have the current date displayed in a view within my rails app. I'd like the following format: Day of week, Month, Day, Year.

Currently I am using:

```
<%= Time.now.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %>
```

This displays everything but the day of the week. How do I add the day of the week?

Comment: See http://apidock.com/ruby/Time/strftime.

Comment: The [Date.strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) docs.... `%a` or `%A`

Comment: Rails also have to_date and to_datetime methods for date conversion, see http://apidock.com/rails/String/to_date , http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/String/to_datetime

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**%A** gives the day of the week

Customize how you prefer it!

```
<%= Time.now.strftime("%B %d, %Y, %A") %>
```

Comment: My bad %A is the one.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the the name of the day as follows:

```
Time.now.strftime("%B %d, %Y %a") # => "January 18, 2014 Sat"
Time.now.strftime("%B %d, %Y %A") # => "January 18, 2014 Saturday"
```

You can also get day names from numbers `0...7` using `Date::DAYNAMES` like this:

```
require 'date'
(0...7).each { |x| puts Date::DAYNAMES[x] }
 # Sunday
 # Monday
 # Tuesday
 # Wednesday
 # Thursday
 # Friday
 # Saturday
 # => 0...7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%A` to display the full name e.g. *Monday* or `%a` for an abbreviated name e.g. *Mon*:

```
Time.now.strftime("%A, %B %d %Y") # => "Sunday, January 19, 2014"
Time.now.strftime("%a, %B %d %Y") # => "Sun, January 19, 2014"
```

Refer to the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the followings: 
`distance_of_time_in_words(from_time, to_time)` or 
`time_ago_in_words(from_time)`

For example: 
`<span class="posted">Posted on <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago</span>`